# using txt file as input for python

Tags: python, text

I have a python program that requires the user to paste texts into it to process them to the various tasks. Like this:

```
line=(input("Paste text here: ")).lower()
```

The pasted text comes from a .txt file. To avoid any issues with the code (since the text contains multiple quotation marks), the user has to do the following: type 3 quotation marks, paste the text, and type 3 quotation marls again.

Can all of the above be avoided by having python read the .txt? and if so, how?

Please let me know if the question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python2, just use [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) to receive input as a string. No extra quotation marks on the part of the user are necessary.

```
line=(raw_input("Paste text here: ")).lower()
```

Note that [input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) is equivalent to

```
eval(raw_input(prompt))
```

and applying `eval` to user input is dangerous, since it allows the user to evaluate arbitrary Python expressions. A malicious user could delete files or even [run arbitrary functions](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) so never use `input` in Python2!

In Python3, `input` behaves like `raw_input`, so there your code would have been fine.

If instead you'd like the user to type the name of the file, then

```
filename = raw_input("Text filename: ")
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    line = f.read()
```

---

**Troubleshooting:**

Ah, you are using Python3 I see. When you open a file in `r` mode, Python tries to decode the `bytes` in the file into a `str`. If no encoding is specified, it uses `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` as the default encoding. Apparently that is not the right encoding for your file. If you know what encoding your file is using, it is best to supply it with the `encoding` parameter:

```
open(filename, 'r', encoding=...)
```

Alternatively, a hackish approach which is not nearly as satisfying is to ignore decoding errors:

```
open(filename, 'r', errors='ignore')
```

A third option would be to read the file as bytes:

```
open(filename, 'rb')
```

Of course, this has the obvious drawback that you'd then be dealing with bytes like `\x9d` rather than characters like `·`.

Finally, if you'd like some help guessing the right encoding for your file, run

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(repr(contents))
```

and post the output.

Comment: ok, this worked as a charm, however i got the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rodrigof\Desktop\py\experiment with text.py", line 18, in <module>
    line = f.read()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1755: character maps to <undefined>

line 18 is:

line = f.read()

i believe it is because the text contains this:  · is there a way ignore unknown characters?

Comment: I've posted some suggestions on how to deal with this problem above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
with open("file.txt") as fl:
    file_contents = [x.rstrip() for x in fl]
```

This will result in the variable `file_contents` being a list, where each element of the list is a line of your file with the newline character stripped off the end.

If you want to iterate over each line of the file, you can do this:

```
with open("file.txt") as fl:
    for line in fl:
        # Do something
```

The `rstrip()` method gets rid of whitespace at the end of a string, and it is useful for getting rid of the newline character.